# Not able to view the uploaded image on a server

Tags: java, android

when I try to upload an image on a server it's showing "image uploaded successfully" on my device, but I am not able to see the image on the server.
I even tried to upload the image by converting it into Base64.

Here is my code.

```
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.i(TAG, "doFileUpload Response : " + responseStr);
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

}

public String convertBitmapToString(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    String imageStr = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageStr;
}
```

But at run time it's showing an error:

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f9e668360
```

Comment: You are uploading from your server to your phone or from your phone to server?

Comment: Why do u send the image as `String` instead of `byte[]`?

Comment: thanks for your response .am uploading image from phone to server.... Orkun Koçyiğit

Comment: Can you please let me know the code...thanks in advance. sam

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                final JSONObject jsonObject = uploadImage(strImagePath);
                                if (jsonObject != null) {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Response : " + jsonObject.toString());
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();



public JSONObject uploadImage(String profileFileUri) {
        try {

            RequestBody r = null;
            RequestBody k = null;
            String extension = null;
            String ext = null;


            if (profileFileUri != null) {
                File sourceFile = new File(profileFileUri);

                Log.d(TAG, "File...::::" + sourceFile + " : " + sourceFile.exists());

                final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");
                final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPG = MediaType.parse("image/jpg");
                final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
                final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_GIF = MediaType.parse("image/gif");

                if (profileFileUri.contains(".jpg")) {
                    k = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, sourceFile);
                    ext = ".jpg";
                } else if (profileFileUri.contains(".jpeg")) {
                    ext = ".jpeg";
                    k = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG, sourceFile);
                } else if (profileFileUri.contains(".png")) {
                    ext = ".png";
                    k = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile);
                } else if (profileFileUri.contains(".gif")) {
                    ext = ".gif";
                    k = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_GIF, sourceFile);
                }
            }

            MultipartBody requestBody;

            if (k != null) {


                requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)


                        .addFormDataPart("first_name", strFname)
                        .addFormDataPart("last_name", strLname)
                        .addFormDataPart("email", strEmail)
                        .addFormDataPart("gender", strGender)
                        .addFormDataPart("mobile", strMobile)
                        .addFormDataPart("birth_date", strBirthdate)
                        .addFormDataPart("profile_pic", "IMG" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ext, k)
                        .addFormDataPart("access_token", UserInfo.getAccessToken())
                        .build();

            } else {


                requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)


                        .addFormDataPart("first_name", strFname)
                        .addFormDataPart("last_name", strLname)
                        .addFormDataPart("email", strEmail)
                        .addFormDataPart("gender", strGender)
                        .addFormDataPart("profile_pic", "")
                        .addFormDataPart("mobile", strMobile)
                        .addFormDataPart("birth_date", strBirthdate)
                        .addFormDataPart("access_token", UserInfo.getAccessToken())
                        .build();


            }


            Log.d(TAG, "uploadImage param  : " + requestBody.toString());
            okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                    .url(Consts.URL.EDIT_PROFILE)
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();


            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String res = response.body().string();

            Log.d(TAG, "Response : " + res);
            return new JSONObject(res);

        } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {


            Error.displayNetworkErrorDialog(ProfileActivity.this);

            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Error.displayNetworkErrorDialog(ProfileActivity.this);
            Log.e(TAG, "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Please try this code to upload image to server....!
I hope it's helpful to you ...!